# Can I have multiple $_GET with the same key, different values?

Tags: php, get

Is it possible to retrieve the arguments from a url where the same $_GET has different values?

Such as `www.domain.com/?user=1&user=2`

Currently this only shows whatever is listed second, so if I `echo $_GET['user']`, it would output `2`

I couldn't seem to find this on SO, so if I missed it please let me know.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php), `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is all you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use user[] as key. should work. [PHP access all $_POST[] variables into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345859/php-access-all-post-variables-into-an-array)

Comment: Thanks! Just when I found the answer I check back and you got it too! I forgot it'd be the same as the checkbox/radios. So i'll be using ?user[]=1&user[]=2. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Quick answer is no.

```
http://localhost/?user=1&user=2
```

Gets you:

```
array
    'user' => string '2' (length=1)
```

However, by including brackets in the query like this:

```
http://localhost/?user[]=1&user[]=2
```

You can retrieve $_GET['user'] and be returned with this:

```
array
    'user' => 
        array
            0 => string '1' (length=1)
            1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The query string gets parsed into the associative array `$_GET`, so when there are duplicated keys only the last version of the value is present on the map. You can however access the raw `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and parse it on your own.

If possible, it would we best if you modify your code to not duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a foreach loop for each $_GET and then group all the 'user' variables into a single array and then access the whichever key value you need. 0 being the first, 1 being the second, and so on...