# Using $_GET with multiple parameters in URL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the url:

```
php?id=1
```

and I currently use

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$tPerson_SQLselect = "SELECT FROM jobList WHERE id = '$id'"
```

And this works fine.

However I am unsure what do when I have the url:

```
php?id=1,2
```

and I want to get and then filter for id= 1 and 2

Many thanks

Comment: Use the symbol Ampersand "&".
Try this: php?id=1&example=2

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: `SELECT FROM jobList` - Um... select what? *"And this works fine."* - Oh?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try using `explode()` & `implode()`. Also use `IN` in query string. Example:

```
$ids = "'" . implode("','", array_filter(explode(',', $_GET['id']))) . "'";
$tPerson_SQLselect = "SELECT * FROM jobList WHERE id IN(".$ids.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like `php?id=1&id=2`, you can use `id[]` as key.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678918/can-i-have-multiple-get-with-the-same-key-different-values)